# What data-structure/algorithm will allow me to send a list of key/value dictionaries using the least amount of bits?

Tags: networking, multiplayer, client-server, data-structures, compression

I have server objects that have corresponding client objects. The data to be kept in sync is inside the server object's key/value dictionary. To keep the client objects in sync with the sever objects, I want the server to send the key/value dictionary every frame for each object.

What data-structure/algorithm will allow me to send a list of key/value dictionaries using the least amount of bits?

Bonus constraint 1: For each type of object, the values of some keys change more often than others.
Bonus constraint 2: Memory usage on the server side is relatively expensive.

Comment: Would you please accept an answer? (Given that you still visit, of course.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You don't need to send the whole dictionary.** Instead, send just what's changed.

**You don't need to send it each frame.** Instead, send it on regular intervals that have nothing to do with the frame rate.

An important idea to keep in mind in the second point is that clients can *predict* changes in game state - the game can go on to be simulated in between receiving information from the server, and then only has to *correct* the mistakes after it receives authoritative information from the server again.

Answer (score 0):

There are no special data structures or algorithms. Transferring delimited data is enough.

Example data (as a C string, note the "\\" which is actually a "\"): `key1;value1;key2;value2;key3\\;with delimiter inside it;value3;\0`

You can choose which keys you send, it's easy to read* and write**, takes little memory and can even be compressed (since it's just one stream of bytes).

*-Read:

```
while( peekbyte() != 0 )
{
    key = readuntil( ';' ); // checks if previous byte isn't "\" while looking for char.
    value = readuntil( ';' );
    add( key, value );
}
```

**-Write:

```
foreach( key in keylist )
{
    write( replace( ';', '\\;', key ) );
    write( replace( ';', '\\;', dict[ key ] ) );
}
write( '\0' );
```